# Find $a_n:a_{n+1}$ if $a_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nx.\cos nx.dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

> Find $a_n:a_{n+1}$ if $a_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nx.\cos nx.dx$

**Attempt 1**
\begin{align}
&a_{n+1}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{n+1}x.\cos(n+1)x.dx\\
&=\frac{\sin (n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^{n+1}x-(n+1)\int\cos^{n}x.\frac{\sin (n+1)x}{(n+1)}.dx\\
&=\frac{\sin (n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^{n+1}x-\int\cos^{n}x.{\sin (n+1)x}dx\\
&=\frac{\sin (n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^{n+1}x-\bigg[\frac{-\cos(n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^nx\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad-n\int\cos^{n-1}x.\frac{-\cos(n+1)x}{n+1}.dx\bigg]\\
&=\frac{\sin (n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^{n+1}x+\frac{\cos(n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^nx\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad+\frac{n}{n+1}\int\cos^{n-1}x.\big(\cos nx.\cos x-\sin nx\sin x\big)dx\\
&=\frac{\sin (n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^{n+1}x+\frac{\cos(n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^nx\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad+\frac{n}{n+1}\bigg[\color{red}{\int\cos^nx\cos nxdx}+\int\cos^{n-1}x.\sin x.\sin nx.dx\bigg]\\
&=\frac{\sin (n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^{n+1}x+\frac{\cos(n+1)x}{n+1}.\cos^nx\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad+\frac{n}{n+1}\bigg[\color{red}{a_n}+\int\cos^{n-1}x.\sin x.\sin nx.dx\bigg]
\end{align}

I don't think it is leading anywhere, is there any trickier way to see the solution ?

**Note:** The solution given in my reference is $2:1$ and I understand that $$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nx.dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nx.dx=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{(n-1)(n-3)....2}{n(n-2)....1}\quad\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\dfrac{(n-1)(n-3)....1}{n(n-2)....2}\quad\text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}
$$

Thanks @Math1000,

**Attempt 2**
\begin{align}
a_n &= \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos^n x\cos nx\ \mathsf dx = \frac{1}{2.2^n} \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(e^{i x}+e^{-i x}\right)^n \left(e^{i n x}+e^{-i n x}\right) \, dx\\
I_1&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(e^{i x}+e^{-i x}\right)^n e^{i n x}.dx\\
&=\bigg[(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^n\frac{e^{inx}}{in}\bigg]_0^{\pi/2}-n\int(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^{n-1}\frac{e^{i n x}}{in}.dx\\
&=\frac{1}{in}-n\int(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^{n-1}\frac{e^{i n x}}{in}.dx\\
I_2&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(e^{i x}+e^{-i x}\right)^n e^{-i n x}.dx\\
&=\bigg[(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^n\frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}\bigg]_0^{\pi/2}-n\int(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^{n-1}\frac{e^{-i n x}}{-inx}.dx\\
&=\frac{-1}{in}+n\int(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^{n-1}\frac{e^{-i n x}}{in}.dx\\
a_n&=\frac{i}{4}\bigg(\int_0^{\pi/2}(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^{n-1}e^{i n x}.dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^{n-1}e^{-i n x}.dx\bigg)\\
&=\frac{i}{2^{n+1}}\int_0^{\pi/2}(e^{i x}+e^{-i x})^{n-1}\Big(e^{i n x}-e^{-i n x}\Big).dx
\end{align}

Comment: +1 for this nice question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}[1]{\, \mathrm{d}#1}$
It's easier to start by expanding $\cos{(n+1)x}$.
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} &= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+1}{x}\cos{(n+1)x} \d{x} \\
&= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+1}{x}(\cos{nx}\cos{x} - \sin{nx}\sin{x}) \d{x} \\
&= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} - \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin{x}\cos^{n+1}{x}\sin{nx} \d{x}
\end{align*}
Let's first look at the second term. Integrating by parts yields:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin{x}\cos^{n+1}{x}\sin{nx} \d{x} &= \left[-\frac{1}{n+2}\cos^{n+2}{x}\sin{nx}\right]_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}} + \frac{n}{n+2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} \\
&= \frac{n}{n+2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x}
\end{align*}
Back to $a_{n+1}$:
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} &= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} - \frac{n}{n+2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} \\
&= \frac{2}{n+2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x}
\end{align*}
We now examine the term in RHS. Integrating by parts again:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} &= \left[\frac{1}{n}\cos^{n+2}{x}\sin{nx}\right]_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}} + \frac{n+2}{n}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin{x}\cos^{n+1}{x}\sin{nx} \d{x} \\
&= \frac{n+2}{n}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin{x}\cos^{n+1}{x}\sin{nx} \d{x} \\
&= \frac{n+2}{n}\left[-\frac{1}{n}\sin{x}\cos^{n+1}{x}\cos{nx}\right]_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}} + \frac{n+2}{n^2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} (\cos^{n+2}{x} - (n+1)\sin^2{x}\cos^n{x})\cos{nx} \d{x} \\
&= \frac{n+2}{n^2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} - \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n^2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^2{x}\cos^n{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} \\
&= \frac{n+2}{n^2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} - \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n^2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} (1 - \cos^2{x})\cos^n{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} \\
&= \left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)^2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} - \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n^2}\color{red}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^n{x}\cos{nx} \d{x}}
\end{align*}
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
&\left(1 - \left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)^2\right)\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} = -\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n^2}a_n \\
&\implies \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^{n+2}{x}\cos{nx} \d{x} = \frac{n+2}{4}a_n
\end{align*}
Substituting back finally yields the desired result:
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}a_n
$$

Answer (score 3):

There is a closed form for $a_n$:
$$
a_n = \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos^n x\cos nx\ \mathsf dx = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(e^{i x}+e^{-i x}\right)^n \left(e^{i n x}+e^{-i n x}\right) \, dx = \frac\pi{2^{n+1}}.
$$

Comment: This is interesting. Could you please explain a bit more on how do you integrate the function in the form of complex exponentials?

Comment: From $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$, $\cos(-x)=\cos x$, and $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$ we get $\cos x = \frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$, and integrating the exponential function is straightforward (e.g. $\int e^{ix}\ \mathsf dx = -ie^{ix} + C$).

Comment: Well, now I am not so sure. Mathematica just gave me
$$
\int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \cos^nx\cos nx\ \mathsf dx = \frac\pi{2^{n+1}}.
$$
I suspect this to be the actual result considering it is a function of $n$.

Comment: I tried to follow as u suggested. but its not going properly i think, may be because I am not familiar with integrating functions like this, could you please help me to find the solution ?

Comment: Something went wrong there. You have $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$, thus $\cos^n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n$

Comment: edited OP, please check.

Comment: still I am not able to evaluate the complex integral, could you comment on that ?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{a_{n}} & \equiv
\color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\cos\pars{nx}\,\dd x} =
\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\expo{\ic nx}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\pars{z + 1/z \over 2}^{n}z^{n}
\,{\dd z \over \ic z}\right\vert_{\, z\ \equiv\ \exp\pars{\ic x}} =
\left.{1 \over 2^{n}}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\pars{1 + z^{2}}^{n} \over z}
\,\dd z\right\vert_{\, z\ \equiv\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\end{align}
*"Close"* the integration -with an indent around $\ds{z = 0}$- in a quarter circle in the complex plane first quadrant. Namely,
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{a_{n}} & \equiv
\color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\cos\pars{nx}\,\dd x} =
\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\expo{\ic nx}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 2^{n}}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\pars{1 + z^{2}}^{n} \over z}
\,\dd z\right\vert_{\, z\ \equiv\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] & \sr{{\rm as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}
-\,{1 \over 2^{n}}\,\ \overbrace{\Im\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}{\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{n} \over \ic y}\,\ic\,\dd y}^{\ds{= 0}}\ -\
{1 \over 2^{n}}\,\Im\ \overbrace{\int_{\pi/2}^{0}{1 \over \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta}
^{\ds{= -\pi\ic/2}}
\\[2mm] &
- {1 \over 2^{n}}\,\ \overbrace{\Im\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\pars{1 + x^{2}}^{n} \over x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{= 0}}\ =\ \bbx{\color{#44f}{\pi \over 2^{n + 1}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ and $\cos x= \Re(e^{ix})$, we can express the integrals into an exponential function.$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^n x \cos n x d x = & \Re \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{e^{x i}+e^{-x i}}{2}\right)^n e^{n x i} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{2^n} \Re\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(e^{x i}\right)^{n-k} e^{-x i k} e^{n x i} d x\right] \\
= & \frac{1}{2^n}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \Re \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{2(n-k) x i} d x\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
For any $k\ne n$, $$
\Re\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{2(n-k) x i} d x = \Re\left[\frac{e^{2(n-k) x i}}{2(n-k) i}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=0
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$
a_n  =\frac{1}{2^n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
n
\end{array}\right) \frac{\pi}{2} =\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}
$$
Hence $$\boxed{a_n:a_{n+1}=2}$$

---

In general, $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^n x \cos m x d x= \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
\frac{m+n}{2}
\end{array}\right) $$